# Select Menu Builder

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Can anyone help me by sending to me SelectMenuBuilder simple project using discord.js 14.14.1

i tired soo much

```
const { MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu, MessageSelectOption } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    async execute(message) {
        const select = new MessageSelectMenu()
            .setCustomId('starter')
            .setPlaceholder('Make a selection!')
            .addOptions(
                new MessageSelectOption()
                    .setLabel('Bulbasaur')
                    .setDescription('The dual-type Grass/Poison Seed Pokémon.')
                    .setValue('bulbasaur'),
                new MessageSelectOption()
                    .setLabel('Charmander')
                    .setDescription('The Fire-type Lizard Pokémon.')
                    .setValue('charmander'),
                new MessageSelectOption()
                    .setLabel('Squirtle')
                    .setDescription('The Water-type Tiny Turtle Pokémon.')
                    .setValue('squirtle'),
            );

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(select);

        await message.channel.send({
            content: 'Choose your starter!',
            components: [row],
        });
    },
};
```

just send me simple project using thats constructure

Comment: What's the problem with the above code? A question should include a problem description, but as far as I can see, you're asking for a "simple project".

Comment: i forgot cuz i deleted the project can u give me a project using selectMenuBuilder ?